# Hibernate Search not working for many to many relationship

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I have two entities `Restaurant` and `Category`, related by a many-to-many relation. I want to search a restaurant by `category_name` but i am not able to get correct results for my search, even though I can see that list is being populated correctly with the data. The entities are:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "restaurant")
@Indexed
public class Restaurant implements Comparable<Restaurant> {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "restaurant_category", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private List<Category> listOfCategories;
}
```

This is the category entity

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "category")
 @Indexed
 public class Category {

 @Column(name = "category_name")
 @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
 private String categoryName;
```

and this my search query

```
Query query = queryBuilder.keyword()
            .onFields("listOfCategories.categoryName").matching("Pub")
            .createQuery();


    org.hibernate.Query hibernateQuery = fullTextSession
            .createFullTextQuery(query, Restaurant.class);

    List<Restaurant> searchResults = hibernateQuery.list();
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you describe what results you are getting and what you would expect? With an example? The code itself looks ok.

Comment: @Hardy I am getting empty list always, although 'pub' keyword exists in category_name in the DB.

Comment: You say that the pub keyword exists in the database, but does it also exist in the Lucene index? Did you build the Lucene index (by either inserting some test entities and relying on auto-indexing or by using the explicit indexing API?) If you have an index, have you inspected it with Luke in order to verify the indexed terms?